# Subsonic. Ambiguous column name using Group By

Tags: .net, subsonic

I'm using subsonic 2.2 with .net 2.0 and I'm having an error when I included "Group By".

Originally I had this code, and it worked perfectly:

```
    SqlQuery etResourceTitle = new Select(ResTitleOngoing.Columns.ResourceTitleID,
                                          ResTitleOngoing.Columns.ResourceTitle, 
                                          VenVendor.Columns.Title,
                                          ResTitleOngoingStatus.Columns.Status).From(Tables.ResTitleOngoing);

    etResourceTitle.InnerJoin(ResTitleOngoingStatus.ResourceTitleIDColumn, ResTitleOngoing.ResourceTitleIDColumn);
    etResourceTitle.LeftOuterJoin(VenVendor.VendorIDColumn, ResTitleOngoing.VendorIDColumn);

    etResourceTitle.OrderAsc(ResTitleOngoing.Columns.ResourceTitle);

    etResourceTitle.ExecuteDataSet();
```

Then I added "Group By", so this is my code:

```
    SqlQuery etResourceTitle = new Select(Aggregate.GroupBy(ResTitleOngoing.Columns.ResourceTitleID),
                                          Aggregate.GroupBy(ResTitleOngoing.Columns.ResourceTitle), 
                                          Aggregate.GroupBy(VenVendor.Columns.Title),
                                          Aggregate.GroupBy(ResTitleOngoingStatus.Columns.Status)).From(Tables.ResTitleOngoing);

    etResourceTitle.InnerJoin(ResTitleOngoingStatus.ResourceTitleIDColumn, ResTitleOngoing.ResourceTitleIDColumn);
    etResourceTitle.LeftOuterJoin(VenVendor.VendorIDColumn, ResTitleOngoing.VendorIDColumn);

    etResourceTitle.OrderAsc(ResTitleOngoing.Columns.ResourceTitle);

    etResourceTitle.ExecuteDataSet();
```

I got the error: "Ambiguous column name 'ResourceTitleID'."

Executing etResourceTitle.BuildSqlStatement(); i got:

SELECT ResourceTitleID AS 'GroupByOfResourceTitleID', 
       ResourceTitle AS 'GroupByOfResourceTitle', 
       Title AS 'GroupByOfTitle', 
       Status AS 'GroupByOfStatus'
FROM [dbo].[RES_TitleOngoing]
INNER JOIN [dbo].[RES_TitleOngoingStatus] ON [dbo].[RES_TitleOngoing].[ResourceTitleID] = [dbo].[RES_TitleOngoingStatus].[ResourceTitleID]
LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[VEN_Vendor] ON [dbo].[RES_TitleOngoing].[VendorID] = [dbo].[VEN_Vendor].[VendorID]
GROUP BY ResourceTitleID, ResourceTitle, Title, Status
ORDER BY ResourceTitle ASC

So, someone can help me with this error.

Thanks
Alan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both your tables RES_TitleOngoing and RES_TitleOngoingStatus contain a column named ResourceTitleID but you specified just ResourceTitleID in your group by part so the sql server does not know which ResourceTitleID you want to group.

Note:

```
ResTitleOngoing.Columns.ResourceTitleID
```

just returns a string "ResourceTitleID"

You should try one of these instead:

```
Aggregate.GroupBy(ResTitleOngoing.ResourceTitleIDColumn)
Aggregate.GroupBy(ResTitleOngoing.Schema.QualifiedName + "."
                  + ResTitleOngoing.Columns.ResourceTitleID)
```

Comment: Thanks SchlaWiener.

This resolved my problem. I used 
Aggregate.GroupBy(ResTitleOngoing.ResourceTitleIDColumn) 

Alan